# Get Values of array with reference to other array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array `a= ["APP","COM", "REJ" , "COM APP"]` and `b= [23,54,56,24].` `A and B` are of equal length.
How to get all elements of array B, in which the values of array a contains VALUE as APP

here in array a there is an APP in APP , COM APP , how to `return [23, 24] as a an array.

Comment: **Basic idea:** Create array C. Iterate through array A - if an item of A is not empty, add a corresponding item from array B to array C. Do it yourself, you won't learn anything, if other people write code for you.

Answer (score 2):

```js
var a= ["3","", "6"];
var b= [23,54,56];

function selector(e, i){ return {e, i}; }
function filter(e){ return e.e != "" }
function selector2(e){ return b[e.i] }

var c = a.map(selector).filter(filter).map(selector2);
console.log(c);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use filter to acheive what you need. Here is what you could do.

```js
var a = ["3", "", "6"];
var b = [23, 54, 56];

var result = b.filter((val, idx) => a[idx] !== "");


var resultWithEs5 = b.filter(function(val, idx) {
  return a[idx] !== "";
});

console.log(result);

console.log(resultWithEs5);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a for loop to get the result

```js
var a= ["3","", "6"], b= [23,54,56], c = [];
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
   if(a[i] !== "" && b[i])
       c.push(b[i])
}

console.log(c)
```

Comment: I updated your answer to use "!==" instead of "!=".  "!=" is bad form for most equality comparisons in javascript

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using Array filter method.

```js
    a= ["3","", "6"];  
    b= [23,54,56];
    result = b.filter((ele, index) => {
     return a[index] !== ''; // your condition, here is not false.
    })
    console.log(result)
```

Detail link: [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution. Hope it helps!

```js
var a= ["3","", "6"], b= [23,54,56]

var element = "";

for(var i in a){
    if(a[i] == ""){
      element = i;
    }
}
var index = b.indexOf(b[element]);

if (index > -1) {
    b.splice(index, 1);
}
console.log(b)
```